# How to select the drop down using selenium webdriver. I have added the code

Tags: selenium-webdriver, webdriver

[image: Refer the Code]

I have to select the any one static check box.
Steps2: Select the invisible drop down text from the list

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML example does not have drop-down. Take a look at a simple illustration of a drop-down:

```
<select id="mySelect">
<option value="option1">France</option>
<option value="option2">Italy</option>
<option value="option3">Spain</option>
</select>
```

You have an unordered HTML list. Take a look at [w3school example](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_ul.asp).

So you should work with it like with a common List.